# I want every time the user Upload the image it will display using Firebase and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I using Firebase storage and Firestore to upload Images I have this Code to make this happen:

```
    // store uploaded Images
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    // store imagesUrls from firebase storage
    const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    


    const handleChange = (e) => {

      e.preventDefault()
    //getting the images the user uploads
        for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
          const newImage = e.target.files[i];
          newImage["id"] = Math.random();
          setImages((prevState) => [...prevState, newImage]);
        }

   //then upload them to firebase storage

        const promises = [];
        images.map((image) => {
          const uploadTask = dbStorage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
          promises.push(uploadTask);
          uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
              const progress = Math.round(
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
              );
              setProgress(progress);
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            },
    
      // then waits for the imagesURLs and append them to the urlsArray
            async () => {
              await dbStorage
                .ref("images")
                .child(image.name)
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then((urls) => {
                  setUrls((prevState) => [...prevState, urls]);
                });
            }
          );
        });
    
    
    
        Promise.all(promises)
          .then(() => alert("image uploaded"))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      };
```

then I have this Jsx code to display everything

```
             <div>
                <label className="input__label">
                    Upload Photos<span id="required">*</span>
                </label>

                <input type="file" multiple className="upload__field" onChange={handleChange}/>
                </div>

            {/* then I display the images in the urlsArray */}
                <div>
                {urls.map((url, i) => (
                  <img
                    key={i}
                    src={url || "http://via.placeholder.com/300"}
                    alt="firebase-image"
                    id="uploaded__images"
                  />
                ))}
                </div>
```

This works fine But When I upload images, the 1st attempt does not upload even when I upload them in multiple by pressing Ctrl + click and when I upload again, it uploads.

is there a way to have them upload every time the user upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest  you to go through this [official resource page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)  for the format and

If you still face the issue, point to the specific library method that is not functioning in the way that is expected. You can do this by adding debugging information to your source code or simplify it by removing the async part.

You can check this [example link](https://dev.to/chriseickemeyergh/uploading-multiple-files-with-firebase-in-react-apps-1753) to help you code this functionality.